# Creating a drag and drop menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a menu you can arrange by dragging and dropping menu items on top of eachother. Dropping an item ontop of another should create a submenu and when dropping it on the left/right/top/bottom it should place it accordingly.

To "detect" which direction the menu should be placed, I was thinking of adding overlays to the menu item like so (pardon my painting skills):

[image: div overlays]

The red boxes are the overlay divs I want to add.

My question is: is this the right way to do? Or would a javascript solution with some sort of mouse coordinates in relation to the menu be better? What method would you use (can be any, not just the two I pointed out)?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the library JQuery UI to [sort](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) and [drag&drop](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/).
If the item is located exactly above the other, you need to add it to the item.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for checking mouse events and their coordinates to keep the markup and domtree clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Knockout.js with some modification.

Check [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/dragging-dropping-and-sorting-with.html). Looks like it might help You.

You migh also chectk out [this github project](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable).